# Is there a way to see the borders around all div tags on a web page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am changing a style sheet from Wordpress and customizing it for my own needs.
I do this by going through the style sheet and changing the borders to 1 so i can see where the divs are.
Is there an easy way to see the div's visually in a style sheet so I can know which ones need to be modified?

Answer (score 11):

Use outline instead border. Border can break markup.

```
div {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

To show all div's class names write to console.

```
$('div').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('class'));
})
```

---

**Update:**

You can show all divs classnames via css only.

```
div:after {
    content: attr(class);
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked fantastic.  Now to figure out how to see the names of the div tags!  :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes..

```
* {
border:1px solid red !important;
}
```

This will add a 1px red border to every element on the page.

For just divs change the asterisk to "div".

Comment: Works great too.  I like both solutions.

Comment: @Migpics mind collapsing margin when you do so, if you are not familiar with this, it might make you quiet confused :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css border for this.

```
*{
    border:solid 2px red;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{
border:solid 2px red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>bordersh2>

<p class="one">Some text.</p>
<p class="two">Some text.</p>
<p class="three">Some text.</p>
<p class="four">Some text.</p>
<p class="five">Some text.</p>
<p class="six">Some text.</p>
<p class="seven">Some text.</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> property  alone.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure CSS, there aren't that many possibilites to mark all elements of your selector visually (they could potentialy be hidden as well). For example, you could simply add the rule:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You could consider using Javascript or JQuery to see which elements may be affected. Given a selector "div ~ span:nth-child(3)", the code would be:

**Javascript**

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("div ~ span:nth-child(3)"));
```

**JQuery**

```
console.log($("div ~ span:nth-child(3)"));
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

i usually use box-shadow to avoid disturbing [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) and [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```
div {
box-shadow:0 0 0 2px red;
}
```

or

```
div {
box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px red;
}
```

Any colors or any size does.

you can select  them also from your main IDS or div/section of your template

```
aside div { box-shadow:0 0 0 2px purple}
section div {box-shadow:0 0 0 2px green}
#container div {box-shadow:0 0 0 2px tomato}
/* ... and so on */
```

Same as outline, theres is no after effects

Finally if you wanna see , id and or class name of each you may use a pseudo:

```css
#hello {
  margin:1em;
  }
#hi {
  padding:1em;
  }
.float {
  float:right;
  }
.nofloat {
  color:gray;
  padding:3em;
  }
div {
  position:relative;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px;
}
div:before {
  content:attr(id)' ' attr(class);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin:-4px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
  font-size:0.6em;
  font-family:courier;
  }
```

```html
<div id="hello"> hello</div>
<div id="hi" class="float"> hi !</div>
<div class="nofloat"> i'm a div box</div>
```